# Express session doesn't save ... unless I refresh my browser?

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I'm trying to implement a simple login with node and express, storing the logged-in user's info in an express session. Here's what I've got so far

Application:

```
var express = require("express");
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
var session = require("express-session");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

var app = express();
app.use( cookieParser(SESSION_SECRET) );
app.use( bodyParser.json() );
app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}) );
app.use( session({secret:SESSION_SECRET, resave:true, saveUninitialized:true, cookie:{httpOnly: false, secure:false, maxAge:COOKIE_MAX_AGE}}) );
// a couple app.use statements to serve static files from a public folde
```

My login route does this:

```
router.post("/login", function(request, response)
{
  // authentication stuff. if the user is authenticated:
  request.session.userId = user._id;
  request.session.save();
  response.json({success:true, user: user._id});
});
```

Elsewhere, I have this to automatically inject user info for my other routes:

```
// inject currently-logged-in user info into all requests
router.use(function(request, response, next)
{
    // No session and no user ID means no user. So just go on.
    if( null == request.session || null == request.session.userId )
    {
        console.log("No session here.");
        return next();
    }

    // Try to find the user. Look up the user id in the db, then do this:
    request.user = dbUser;
    next();
});

// External Routes 
require("./routes/Login")(router); // this is where router.post("/login") is
require("./routes/User")(router); // another route that looks up user info
```

What's weird is that after I log in the first time, on subsequent requests I see that the session doesn't exist ("No session here." in the TTY) but when I refresh my browser and log in a *second* time, it's there.

EDIT: So, the simplified order of events are:

1. **client:** http.post("/login", {userid:..,pw:...});
2. **server *user-injector route*:** fails, no session (that's ok because we're about to create one), so call next()
3. **server *login route*:** credentials ok, so it should create a session. then it returns the response to the client.
4. **client:** server says we're good to go, so: http.get("/protectedstuff")
5. **server *user-injector route*:** fails, no sesion (what? it should have been created by this point)

EDIT 2: Some more info. It gets weirder? This seems to only happen right after the server restarts, and only for the first login attempt. Once the first user is able to login and get a session, any other attempt to login will be successful. Even if the first user logs out.

At this point I'm beginning to wonder if there's a bug in express-session. That first call to store a session variable isn't working for some reason.

---

I'm not really sure where the problem is, either. My browser is making pretty simple http requests with angular, and it's storing the user id properly. I can see quite clearly that the json response's data object is {success: true, user: (user id)}, so everything looks ok on that end. I'm stumped. Why isn't express saving my session info in the login route?

Package versions:

- body-parser: 1.12.3
- cookie-parser: 1.3.4
- express: 4.12.3
- express-session: 1.11.1
- angular: 1.3.15

Comment: Is your "inject currently logged in user" middleware being attached before the 'POST /login' route?

Comment: @AndrewLavers Yup. I'll add info about how my router is set up.

Comment: What is the `user` variable?  That looks like a semi-global which looks like trouble anytime multiple requests are in flight at the same time.

Comment: @jfriend00 user is a local variable in the route, the result of a db lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of messing around I finally managed to fix the problem. Or maybe it's just a workaround. The issue was that I wasn't specifying a default store for the session data on the server. So by default, express is using a memory store which, apparently, is not so great.

I'm using connect-mongo as the session store now and things seem to be working, although I still suspect that there's a bug in express somewhere.

For completeness sake, here's how I'm setting up express now:

```
var express = require("express");
var session = require("express-session");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var MongoStore = require("connect-mongo")(session);

var app = express();
// same cookieparser, bodyparser, etc setup as before
app.use( session( {
  secret:SESSION_SECRET, 
  resave: true, 
  saveUninitialized: false,
  rolling: true,
  store: new MongoStore({mongooseConnection:mongoose.connection}),
  cookie: {
      httpOnly: false, 
      secure: false, 
      maxAge:COOKIE_MAX_AGE
  }
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:**

Sorry, I was mistaken, I was thinking the first hit to the `/login` route was the one that was triggering the "No session here." log, which would make sense given the ordering. I've made an edit to make things a bit clearer

Still, I would suggest looking into passport.js instead of rolling your own login code: http://passportjs.org/guide/username-password/

Comment: I don't think this is an issue with the injection middleware. The first time I attempt to login I don't expect to see any session info. However, any other requests after that made through the router, I do expect to see something there in the session. But I don't. I'll add some more info to the order of operations to help explain what's going on a little better.

Comment: Oh I see. Based on the fact that you have to login twice in order for things to work, it seems like your login route is depending on some session state to already exist in order to persist the `session.userId`. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js express store session in memory, cluster would somehow cause memory leak, it works for me to give up cluster.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35802282)